# Javascript: How to print the raw content of a string including carriage returns?

Tags: javascript, string

For example if I have a variable:

```js
const template = `line 1
line 2
line 3`;
```

I want `console.log(template)` to print:

> line 1\nline 2\nline 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just stringify it

```js
const template = `line 1
line 2
line 3`;

console.log(JSON.stringify(template))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks! This should be marked as the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, sonrh!

You can do it something like this:

```js
const template = `line 1
line 2
line 3`;

console.log(template.replace(/\n/g, `\\n`))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all '\n' with '\\n'

```js
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}


const template = `line 1
line 2
line 3`;

console.log(replaceAll(template,'\n', `\\n`));
```